# How to make the WPF Label Selectable?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, label, wpf-controls

I just want to copy the label content from the UI Window. Anybody can help how to make it?

Comment: I think you should remove jqeury-ui-selectable from your tags.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't have to override the entire template. Try this:

```
<TextBox Text="Copy this...">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

The above style should give you a selectable `TextBox` that looks like a `TextBlock` or a `Label`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem as you.
I wanted my labels to be selectable.

I did not find a proper way to do that, instead I use a TextBox with a custom style.

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxAsLabel" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <themes:ClassicBorderDecorator x:Name="Bd" BorderThickness="0" BorderStyle="Sunken" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"/>
                </themes:ClassicBorderDecorator>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

you also need to add this to your namespaces:

```
xmlns:themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Classic"
```

Usage is : `<TextBox Text="{Binding ValueToBind}"  IsReadOnly="True" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxAsLabel}" />`

Note: Change your style binding type as needed.

Hope this will help you :)